# Subquery with highest count inputs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've seen many similar questions, but haven't been able to apply them to my situation.   I've spent many hours struggling with this so I appreciate any help any of you can lend me.

**Background:**
I have a [Mosaic Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omg4t.png) mapping count frequency of two input attributes in relation to one another that I am trying to drive with data.   The data originates from a mysql statement.  There is also some simple filtering which gets applied.    With the dataset I am working with, there are a lot of small values so the data gets a little --- well cluttered.

**Goal:** My goal would be to take the most frequently occurring N items from each input and then lump the remaining in an "other" bin.  (worst-case drop). I'm fairly certain I'll have to use an intricate subquery to do this.   However, it's hard for me to completely wrap my brain around the subquery syntax.

***Note:*** I can handle a SQL result that produces counts or non-counts, but might prefer a count-based output due to performance-constraints and work involved massaging it later.

```
Example:   N=2
input1    input2
a           w
a           w
b           w
b           w
b           w
c           x
d           x
b           y
a           z

Output #1 (Preferred):
input1     input2    count
a           w          2
b           w          3
other       x          2
b           other      1
a           other      1

or 

Output #2:
input1     input2    
a           w
a           w
b           w
b           w
b           w
other       x
other       x
b           other
a           other
```

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT input1,input2 from `table` 
where attr3 != 'aaa'
and attr4 != 'bbb'
and attr5 != 'ccc'
and attr6 != 'ddd'
```

I've been able to modify it to return for use in a subquery...

```
SELECT input1,count(*) FROM `table`
where attr3 != 'aaa'
and attr4 != 'bbb'
and attr5 != 'ccc'
and attr6 != 'ddd'
GROUP BY input1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 2
```

From here I've experimented with LEFT JOIN syntax and UNION but have really been completely unsuccessful in getting anything working.

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use subqueries to find the appropriate values for `input1` and `input2` that occur most frequently.  Then, you can join in this information and re-aggregate:

```
select coalesce(i1.input1, 'other') as input1,
       coalesce(i2.input2, 'other') as input2,
       count(*)
from t left join
     (select input1, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by input1
      order by cnt desc
      limit 2
     ) i1
     on t.input1 = i1.input1 left join
     (select input2, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by input2
      order by cnt desc
      limit 2
     ) i2 
     on t.input2 = i2.input2
group by i1.input1, i2.input2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN input1 NOT IN ('a','b') THEN 'other' ELSE input1 END) as input1,
(CASE WHEN input2 NOT IN ('a','b') THEN 'other' ELSE input2 END) as input2,
COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM myTable
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN input1 NOT IN ('a','b') THEN 'other' ELSE input1 END),(CASE WHEN input2 NOT IN ('a','b') THEN 'other' ELSE input2 END)
```

Use a case statement to categorize your inputs, and then group by those case statements to get the counts.

Comment: I didn't really know upfront the values in the set, otherwise your answer may have worked.   Went with Gordon's -- but thanks for the help and very prompt reply nonetheless